# Textboxes matching table column width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, dynamic-sizing

I have this table with a textbox for each column (they are going to be used for filtering).
The textboxes should be the same width as the corresponding column.

This is as far as I've gotten (simplified version): http://jsfiddle.net/9uUpP/

**Pseudo-code explaining what I am trying to do with my current script:**

```
document ready{
    var index = 0;
    for each(th){
        textboxNr(index).width = this.width;
        index++;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the textboxes doesn't match the columns in width.

**important:** The table + content is generated and may change from time to time, so I have to make a dynamic solution. The number of columns will always be the same, but their width may change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First child will not be 0th child. So index should be 1 initially.

Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). It says children index starts with 1.

Then `px` is not needed in width, just the value does enough. [Check here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Here is the updated working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uUpP/1/)

Your code should be,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var index = 1;
    $("#table th").each(function () {
        $('input[type="text"]:nth-child('+index+')').css('width',$(this).width());
        index = index+1;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need of an extra variable for this, you can use the `index` parameter in the `each` method itself, along with the [`:eq() Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#table th").each(function (index) {
        $('input[type="text"]:eq(' + index + ')').css('width', $(this).width());
    });
});
```

I have used `:eq()` here instead of `:nth-child(n)` since  `:nth-child(n)` uses 1-based indexing to conform to the CSS specification but the `index` parameter in the `each` method starts from `0` and `:eq()` use 0-based indexing.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9uUpP/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the indexes were incorrect...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#table th").each(function (i, v) {
        $('input[type="text"]:nth-child(' + (i+1) + ')').css('width', $(this).width() + 'px');
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/9uUpP/)